# Issue installing Nokogiri Gem w/ Rails: "Could not find "Nokogiri..."

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, nokogiri, bundler

Nokogiri is in my gem file. Bundle install returns the expected output:

```
Using nokogiri (1.4.4) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

When trying to execute db:create:all I get the following error:

```
rake db:create:all
Could not find nokogiri-1.4.4 in any of the sources
```

If I test in irb, I also get the expected output.

```
irb(main):003:0> require "rubygems"
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require "nokogiri"
=> true
```

I have uninstalled and install nokogiri along with its dependencies multiple times.

I'm using:

Rails 3.0.6
Ruby 1.8.7

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: 4/25/11 3:02pm EDT**

For comment below: Gemfile line for nokogiri is

```
gem "nokogiri", '1.4.4', :require => "nokogiri"
```

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: What's your `GEM_HOME` set to? It's possible that it's installed somewhere unusual and Ruby can't find it. `Rakefile` uses `Gemfile`, but your `irb` example does not.

Comment: How do I check what my GEM_HOME is set too?

Answer (score 2):

I made a test with your case in mind.
My Gemfile is like this:

```
gem "nokogiri", '1.4.4', :require => "nokogiri"
```

And then `rake db:migrate` worked just fine

Comment: Nokogiri was already in the gemfile, but I added the ":require => "nokogiri"" segment. Both Rake db:migrate and Rake db:create:all still return: "Could not find nokogiri-1.4.4 in any of the sources"

Comment: This worked for me.  I think the problem was maybe that even though i had the nokogiri gem, it was only there as a dependency of capybara, or one of the other gems that was in the `:test` block of my Gemfile, and so it wasn't appearing in my development env.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a long shot but you could try:

```
bundle install --no-deployment
```

If you are in deployment mode Rails will look for your gems in the vendor directory, rather then the usual install location. It can cause this kind of error.